# please how do i fix this issue..? i am trying to make a webscraper

Tags: web, web-scraping, spyder

No such file or directory: 'hackathon.html'
this is an error while running the code on spyder

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('hackathon.html','r') as html_file:
    content=html_file.read()
print(content)
```

`\\hackathon.html` is saved on my desktop

Answer (score 0):

Put the file in the directory you are running your script or give `open()` the full path information.